# Did SQL 2008 SP3 break INSERT HASHBYTES for anyone else? (it turns out to be an issue with an INT parm)

Tags: sql-server-2008

**EDIT:**  It turns out that the problem was with an input parm.  Apparently, if you have an input parm of type INT with a default value of NULL (i.e. @MaxSeqKey int = NULL) and you use that parm in a WHERE clause it can SOMETIMES cause the "hang" issue.  What is really weird is that it has been running fine for several months and suddenly broke when SP3 was applied.  Since this is part of a batch job we have not run it in test since it was moved to prod.  Our test server also has SP3 on it so I ran it in test after I posted this question.  Behold!  It works fine in test.  Go figure.  The work around our DBAs found was to DECLARE an internal INT variable in the proc and SET the internal variable equal to the parm.  Once again, go figure.  Whatever.  It works so I wanted to share it with the community.

SQL 10.0.5500 (2008 SP3, NOT 2008R2)

We have a batch job that kicks off a stored proc.  The stored proc has the following TSQL in it.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE h
    SET h.PreviousHash = h.CurrentHash
    ,h.CurrentHash = HASHBYTES('SHA1', ISNULL(m.[Name],'') + ISNULL(m.[Address],'') + ISNULL(m.[City],'') + ISNULL(m.[State],'') + ISNULL(m.[Zip],'') )
    FROM [Hash] h 
    INNER JOIN m WITH(NOLOCK) ON m.SequenceKey = h.SequenceKey
    WHERE h.SequenceKey <= @MaxSeqKey


    INSERT INTO [Hash] (SequenceKey, CurrentHash, PreviousHash, Name, [Address], City, Zip)
    SELECT m.SequenceKey
        ,HASHBYTES('SHA1', ISNULL(m.[Name],'') + ISNULL(m.[Address],'') + ISNULL(m.[City],'') + ISNULL(m.[State],'') + ISNULL(m.[Zip],'') )
        ,NULL --PreviousHash - this indicates a "new" record
        ,m.Name
        ,m.[Address]
        ,m.City
        ,m.Zip
    FROM Merchants m WITH(NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN [Hash] h ON h.SequenceKey = m.SequenceKey
    WHERE h.SequenceKey IS NULL
    AND m.SequenceKey <= @MaxSeqKey

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

This is the first part of the proc.  This was running fine every night until they installed SQL 2008 SP3 this past weekend.  At first we thought the UPDATE followed by the INSERT to the same table was the problem but we commented out the UPDATE statement and it still got hung up (it doesn't crash, it just hangs.)  We ran the INSERT statement by itself and it runs fine.  It seems to only be a problem when run in a stored proc.  Since we have other similar statements in stored procs all over our system that just don't use the HASHBYTES function, we can only assume that this is the problem.  I would appreciate it if anyone out there would be willing to take the time to see if they can replicate this.

Comment: I would suspect that you were probably encountering a parameter sniffing or statistics issue and nothing to do with `hashbytes`, `sp3` or default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my **EDIT** above.  HASHBYTES was not the problem.  An input parm of type INT with a default value of NULL was the problem, even after the value was set.